# Undefined exports while exporting promise to another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, connection-pooling

I am trying to make multiple connection pools and export them to other modules so that i can query in other modules as crm1.execute().[I have 15 databases so i have to create 15 pools] I have tried 2 methods (mentioned in code). If i try to export connection without promise i get **undefined** exports in app.js so after some digging i found that i will have to use promise to make sure the connections are exported when i use them in app.js. I have tried to implement promise in method 1 but still getting same thing.

**pool.js**

```js
const config = require("../config/config");
const oracledb = require("oracledb");

//method 1

module.exports.crm1promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oracledb.createPool({
        user: config.crm1.user,
        password: config.crm1.password,
        connectString: config.crm1.connectString,
        poolAlias: config.crm1.poolAlias,
        poolMin: 0,
        poolMax: 10,
        poolTimeout: 300
    }, (error, pool) => {
        if (error) {
            reject(err);
        }

        module.exports.crm1db = pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve (module.exports.crm1db = connection);
        });
    });
});

//method 2

oracledb.createPool({
    user: config.crm2.user,
    password: config.crm2.password,
    connectString: config.crm2.connectString,
    poolAlias: config.crm2.poolAlias,
    poolMin: 0,
    poolMax: 10,
    poolTimeout: 300,
}, (error, pool) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    module.exports.crm2db = oracledb.getConnection(config.crm2.poolAlias, (err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("Connection to CRM2 POOL created");
        return connection;
    });
});
```

**app.js**

```js
const db = require("./db/pool");
const oracledb = require("oracledb");

console.log(db.crm1Promise);

console.log(db.exports);
```

**cmd output**

> D:\Development\node\database>node app.js 
>   **undefined**
>   **undefined**
>   Connection to CRM2 POOL created

Comment: Have you tried using Promise.all ? check it out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: It's `db.crm1promise`, not `db.crm1Promise`. Apart from that it should work (but assigning `module.exports.crm1db`  is pointless). For why method 2 does not work, see the duplicate.